# Mongodb (using typescript) - findOne filter converts _id of type number to string

Tags: mongodb, typescript

The Mongodb findOne filter appears to convert _id of type number to a string. I'm using typescript.

Typescript: version 2.7.2,
Mongodb: 3.0.4,
@types/mongodb: 3.0.5

This does not work:

```
get(id: number): Promise<Dance | null> {
  console.log(id); // id does indeed have the value 1
  return this.Dances.findOne({ _id: id }); // returns null
}
```

I see in the mongodb logs that id had been converted to a string because id is in quotes.

Just to confirm what I saw in the log I hardcoded _id to 1 and it does indeed return a document:

```
get(id: number): Promise<Dance | null> {
  console.log(id); // id does indeed have the value 1
  return this.Dances.findOne({ _id: 1 }); // returns the document
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

I'm using a 4 tier, layered architecture: Client, Api, Domain, Repository. The above code is from the Repository layer.

Here is the relevant code from Api Layer:

Controller action:

```
get(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    DanceService.get(req.params.id).then(r => {
      if (r) res.json(r);
      else res.status(404).end();
    });
}
```

Dance Service:

```
  get(id: number): Promise<Dance> {
    L.info(`fetch dance with id ${id}`);
    return unitOfWork.then(uow =>
      uow.DanceRepository.get(id).then((dance: Dance) => {
        console.log(dance);
        return dance;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is that the same `_id` in your underlying MongoDB collection? Are you not using the default `ObjectId`?

Comment: It's the same _id as in the collection:

Comment: To clarify further. If I use the mongo console I can get the document: db.dances.findOne({_id:1});
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Slow Foxtrot", "description" : "Ballroom dance" }

Comment: Is the `id` coming from a request object?

Comment: Yes it is. I've added the api layer code above.

Comment: In your controller action try parsing the id to int as `DanceService.get(parseInt(req.params.id)).then(r => { ... })`

Comment: You nailed it Sir. That's it. Thanks